# Email not send from drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal-7

I have developed One drupal site . The website is still on my local server(I am using my Development PC as server)
I have created the contact form - But when I submit, it don't send the email. I have done all the configuration for the webform.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a configured mail server on your local machine? probably not!
Also check [this](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) out

Comment: I have installed XAMPP and in the PHP.ini file I have comment out the  SMTP part it looks like this -

[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 SMTP = 192.168.1.16
 smtp_port = 25

But then also mails are not sending from my site .
Any thing else required?